# I can't remove an item from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is what I found online on how to remove an item from an array.
I use splice, but when I open the console it says undefined.
How can I remove the item from the array with jquery or javascript?

Thanks.

```
var images;

    function readURL2(input, where) {
        images = input;
        var counter = 0;
        var html = "";
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    html += "<tr><td><img src='" + e.target.result + "' height='100'></td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeImg(" + counter + ")'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span> Remove</button></rd></tr>";

                    $(where).html(html);
                    counter++;
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function removeImg(imgIndex) {
        images.files.splice(imgIndex, 1);
        console.log(images.files);
        readURL2(images, "#miltiim");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with splice , can u do a console.log right before calling splice ?

Comment: is the console.log(images.files); saying undefined?
If that is the case, you need to create and fill that array

Comment: Not appear `where` defined at OP ?

Answer (score 0):

// Start with an initial array

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

// Find and remove item from an array

```
var i = array.indexOf("b");
if(i != -1) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Of course if you'd like to remove multiple occurrences of the same string/number, you'll need add a bit more logic:

```
for(var i = array.length-1; i--;){
    if (array[i] === "b") array.splice(i, 1);
}
```

You may be thinking that the filter method would work...

```
array.filter(function(i) {
    return i != "b"
});
```

...but that will return a new array, thus not modifying the original.

Removing a given value from an array isn't too difficult of a task when you have a reliable snippet nearby!

### -

source : http://davidwalsh.name/remove-item-array-javascript

Comment: Please check the for loop, it looks like an infinite loop !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you supply the initial index of each image to the remove function, but removing an image changes the index within the `images` array:

```
Initial:
         index
image0   0
image1   1
image2   2
```

`removeImg("1")` will remove image1, you will have:

```
         index
image0   0
image2   1
```

`removeImg("2")` to remove image2 will not work as its index now is 1.

What you should do, and will not require to generate the images each time, is to set an id for each `tr` containing an image and remove it using jquery:

### Html:

```
<tr id='row-image-"+counter+"'>
<td>
<img src='" + e.target.result + "' height='100'>
</td>
<td>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'
        onclick='removeImg(" + counter + ")'>
<span class='fa fa-remove'></span> Remove</button>
</rd>
</tr>
```

### JS:

```
function removeImg(imgIndex) {
    $('#row-image-'+imgIndex).remove();
}
```